# Showing that $(1,\sqrt{2})\in U\subseteq(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)\Longrightarrow \exists p,q\in\mathbb{N} :\Big(1,\frac{p}{q}\Big)\in U$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity, solution-verification

As the title states, I want to show that
$$\tag{1}
(1,\sqrt{2})\in U\subseteq(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)\Longrightarrow \exists p,q\in\mathbb{N} :\Big(1,\frac{p}{q}\Big)\in U,
$$
with $U$ being an open set. Define $(a,b)\times(c,d):=U$. Then saying that $(1,\sqrt{2})\in U$ means that $1\in (a,b)$ and $\sqrt{2}\in (c,d)$. This implies that there exists an open ball
$$
B_{r}(\sqrt{2})=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid d(x, \sqrt{2})<r\} \subseteq (c,d).
$$

Since

$$
\forall r \in \mathbb{R}\ \exists p, q \in \mathbb{N}: d\left(\frac{p}{q}, \sqrt{2}\right)<r
$$ we know that there exist $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{p}{q}\in(c,d)$. Since $(1,\sqrt{2})\in U$, we know that $1\in (a,b)$, and therefore $(1,\frac{p}{q})\in U$.

Does this prove eq. $(1)$ or have I made a mistake?

Comment: There's a mistake right away: there are lots of open sets, and they are not all of the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)$. The fact that $(1,\sqrt2)\in U$ means that there is a particular type of set (an open neighborhood $V$) such that $(1,\sqrt2)\in V$ and $V\subset U$. What definition of open set are you using?

Comment: I am considering the "usual" topology on $\mathbb{R_+}$ with basis consisting of open sets $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R_+}$, and the product topology for $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Take another look about the difference between a _basis for a topology_ and the _topology_ itself (in this case the product topology); that should help you sort out the initial error you made.

Comment: @GregMartin, I forgot to take into accound that $U$ could be a union of open subsets. Would it be correct to write $U=\bigcup_{i\in I, j\in J} (a,b)_i\times (c,d)_j$, with $I,J$ being index sets?

Answer (score 1):

One issue: just because $U$ is an open subset of $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$ does not mean you can write
$$U = (a, b) \times (c, d).$$ However, since open sets of the form $(a, b) \times (c, d)$ form a basis for the topology on $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$, what you can say is that there exists some open $(a, b) \times (c, d)$ such that
$$(1, \sqrt{2}) \in (a, b) \times (c, d) \subseteq U,$$ and then proceed with your proof.

Another minor nitpick: you write that $\sqrt{2} \in (c, d)$ implies that there exists an open ball
$$B_{r}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq U.$$ This is wrong (since an open ball around $\sqrt{2}$  is a subset of $(0, \infty),$ while $U$ is a subset of $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$). What you can say is that there exists an open ball
$$B_{r}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq (c, d),$$ and proceed from there.

Comment: That was a stupid mistake to assume that we can write $U=(a,b)\times (c,d)$. But is it correct that we can write it as $U=\bigcup_{i\in I, j\in J} (a,b)_i\times (c,d)_j$?